# scrapy extracting urls from a simple site

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to extract basic data from a basic site: vapedonia.com. It's a simple ecommerce site and I do it pretty easily "reinventing the wheel" (mainly working on a big html string) but when I have to work in that mold called scrapy, it just does not work.

I first analyze the html code and create my xpath expression using a plugin. In that plugin, everything goes fine but when I create my code (or even when I use the scrappy shell), it doesn't work.

here's the code:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
   name = "vapedonia"
   allowed_domains = ["vapedonia.com"]
   start_urls = ["https://www.vapedonia.com/23-e-liquidos"]

   def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        products = hxs.select("//div[@class='product-container clearfix']")
        for products in products:
            image = products.select("div[@class='center_block']/a/img/@src").extract()
            name = products.select("div[@class='center_block']/a/@title").extract()
            link = products.select("div[@class='right_block']/p[@class='s_title_block']/a/@href").extract()
            price = products.select("div[@class='right_block']/div[@class='content_price']/span[@class='price']").extract()
        print image, name, link, price
```

Here are the errors:

```
C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample>scrapy crawl vapedonia
C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\spiders\test.py:1: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\spiders\test.py:6: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: craigslist_sample.spiders.test.MySpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spiders.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spiders.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
  class MySpider(BaseSpider):
C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\spiders\test2.py:1: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.spiders` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\spiders\test2.py:2: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\spiders\test2.py:2: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml` is deprecated, use `scrapy.linkextractors.sgml` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\spiders\test2.py:13: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: SgmlLinkExtractor is deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Please use scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor
  Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\spiders\test4.py:15: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: SgmlLinkExtractor is deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Please use scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor
  Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(scrapy.cmdline.execute())
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 148, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 243, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 330, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "C:\Users\eric\Miniconda2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\spiders\test5.py", line 17
    link = products.select("div[@class='right_block']/p[@class='s_title_block']/a/@href").extract()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample>
```

I don't know what the problem is but I have several spiders coded spiders in the spiders directory/folder. May be it's some kind of mix of codes between spiders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When scrapy runs it scans for all scrapers present in the project to fine their names and run the one that you specified. So if any scraper has a syntax error then it won't work

```
  File "C:\Users\eric\Documents\Web Scraping\0 - Projets\Scrapy-\projects\craigslist_sample\craigslist_sample\spiders\test5.py", line 17
    link = products.select("div[@class='right_block']/p[@class='s_title_block']/a/@href").extract()
```

As you can see in the exception the error is there in your `test5.py`. Fix the indentation in this file or comment it if you don't need it. That should allow you to run the spider

**Edit-1: Mixing of Tabs and Spaces**

Python is dependent on indentation and a visually same looking indentation may be different in code. It may be using mix of tabs and spaces in different line. Which will cause errors. So make sure to check your editor to show tab and space characters and convert all tabs to spaces.

Comment: I don't understand how I could fix that indentation, I mean: the line 17 is exactly indented as line 16 is and line 16 works fine.

Comment: Visually looking indentation level is not always correct. A line with a tab indentation can visually look same a 4space or 2 spaces depending on the editor settings. So make sure you convert all tabs to spaces and then check

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! Is using notepad++ a problem? I've just counted 4 spaces per tab. Is that OK? Should I better use another editor?

Comment: No need, use Show all characters options in Notepad++. See this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGPyy.png and you should then see spaces and tabs too. Make sure you are not mixing both

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Do you know if there is a way here in stackoverflow to put some screenshots? I've created a new project and created my new spider in it but it still does not work. This "identation error" is driving me crazy!!!

Comment: Don't share screenshot because it would again visual inspection, show the file in dropbox or a pastbin.com link

Comment: What is visual inspection by curiosity? and in Notepad++, Do I need to used spaces or tabs?

Comment: Visual inspection means a person looking at the file from his/her own eyes :-). Use spaces instead of tabs

Comment: Thanks. All clear now. Using spaces instead of tabs could break your relationship with your girlfriend (silicon valley -> TV series) ;-( What I see is that when I create a new line, the next line is automatically tabulated and it is the source of the problem so, I don't know if I have the good intuition here but as I see it, I should always see those arrows and dots explicitly to be sure I'm doing fine. It's surely a matter of habit!

Comment: Sorry to be so lost but it's the first time I'm asking something here. Do I have to close this post in some way? Answering my own question?

Comment: If my answer helped you out then you have to accept it as the answer by click the tick button. If you solved it on your own then you need to post that as answer and accept it

Comment: All right, understood but... where is that "tick button"? I can't see it (it's my very first day here)

Comment: Thanks, now I see it. I clicked it. I hope it helps your reputation in some way as you've helped me out very fast.